# What is the proper way to call the destructor to free up memory in a C++ operator?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble knowing what I'm doing wrong.

```
Huge& Huge::operator *=(const Huge& h) {
    Huge retHuge = *this * h;
    string out1 = retHuge.toString(); // for debugging purposes
    return *this = retHuge;
//  return retHuge;
}
```

The

```
Huge retHuge = *this * h;
```

works fine as I verify in the string `out1`.  If I return retHuge and print the result in the calling routine, I can see that the original this remains unchanged. If I do a `*this = retHuge` and return `*this`, I get a `SEGSEGV` fault.

What is the proper way to call the destructor to clean up memory and to return the result after the multiply?

I would like to thank all of you for the answers. Crazy Eddie used what I had and extended it, which is exactly what I wanted to do. I changed the source to reflect his suggestion and the SEGSEGV fault comes up.

I take this to mean that my syntax must be basically correct but that I have a bug hidden in the rest of my code. This is valuable information and I need to go back and very carefully look to see if I can find something. I don't want to be lazy and ask for help before I do my homework properly, so I'll have a good look first.

My experience is mainly with Java which has a nice garbage collector for unreferenced objects. I'll go through with the debugger and verify that my destructor is being called to free the memory.

That was a good tip to try to do the *= operator first and then build the = operator from it. Clearly I did things in the opposite direction. Still your answers seem to indicate that what I did should indeed work. Since it doesn't work, I'll go back and see if I can find anything. If, after I have done my homework, I still can't find anything, I'll continue to ask. In the meantime, thanks for all the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/140719

Comment: Don't use `delete` in C++ ever. Don't use `new`, either, most of the time, and don't use naked pointers. Problem solved.

Comment: kerrek: while good advice, that actually _doesnt_  solve the problem for once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *not* `delete this`; afterwards, `*this` is writing into unallocated memory.

Instead, just say `*this = retHuge` (without `delete this`), then `return *this`.

Handle deallocation in `operator =` instead.

Here's a complete-ish example, with an imaginary complicated payload of an `int *`:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A(int _val): val(new int(_val))
    { }

    ~A() {
        delete this->val;
    }

    A &operator =(const A &r) {
        // Pretend this->val is complex and we need to reallocate the
        // entire thing.
        delete this->val;

        this->val = new int(*r.val);

        return *this;
    }

    A operator *(const A &r) const {
        return A(*this->val * *r.val);
    }

    A &operator *=(const A &r) {
        return *this = *this * r;
    }

    int *val;
};

int main() {
    A x(5), y(10);
    x *= y;

    std::cout << "x: " << *x.val << ", y: " << *y.val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think usually it's better to implement the arithmetic operators on top of their compound assignment counterparts (i.e, base `*` on `*=`), not the other way around. And usually, it's better to make the non-assigning ones free member functions. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/140719).

Comment: In spite of my checking with the debugger, I wasn't seeing the entire truth. Inside the routine the this looked OK, but after return it would give the SIGSEGV. Your assign operator was the key. I made a 'clean' routine which I used in the destructor and a 'copy' routine which I used in the copy constructor. Now I could call 'clean' to get rid of the previous contents of this, and a 'copy' to insert the new value of the assign into this. So your idea to do the work inside = was the key I was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The [canonical form of overloading arithmetic operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/140719) applied to your specific case:

```
Huge& Huge::operator *=(const Huge& h) // class member function
{
  // somehow multiply h's value into this' value
  return *this;
}


Huge operator*(Huge lhs, const Huge& rhs) // free function; note lhs being copied
{
  lhs *= rhs;  // *= already implemented above
  return lhs;
}
```

There is no dynamic memory involved here at all, hence you do not need to delete any.

The compound assignment form should be a member according to [the operator overloading rules of thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421729/140719) because it changes it's left-hand operand (and is likely to need access to the class' private parts). The non-assigning version should be a free member function so that implicit conversions can be applied equally to both operands.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to already have the * operator, and I'll assume at this point that assignment works, this would be the best implementation:

```
Huge& Huge::operator *=(const Huge& h) {
    Huge retHuge = *this * h;

    return *this = retHuge;
}
```

Comment: Why `retHuge` at all? Once you insist on implementing `*=` on top of `*`, then why not `*this = *this *h`? As it is now, it's just another useless assignment operation.

Comment: Sigh...  I'm not insisting upon anything there bub.  He already has a * operator.  He already has an = operator.  Use them; don't rewrite everything.  He could do what you said and say *this = *this * h but it doesn't matter.  There is NO extra assignment being done here; if you think there is you need to learn the difference between assignment and initialization.  Just because it doesn't look like your answer doesn't mean it's wrong.

Comment: An improvement that might actually matter though would be to use swap instead of =.  A good = operator may very well make additional copies.

Answer (score 0):

`operator=` means you assign the right hand site into **this**.

So, you should change the contents of **this**, and then in the end `return *this;`